# Free form selection in text editor

Tags: text-editors

I regularly need to edit and transform lot of texts. So my dream is to select parts of text in other way (not only inline)

This is a example:

[image: example]

I would like to be able to select for example the red section or purple section of the text. And be able to "search/replace", delete, modify this selection like I can do with the "classical" linear selection.

Is there a text processor who allow to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Quite a few text editors support rectangular selection, e.g. TextMate or Eclipse. I know of no editor that can handle freeform selection. This sounds so odd I have to ask, are you sure this is the problem to need to solve?

Comment: What is the use case for discontinuous and rectangular selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it.. Notepad++ do the stuff with an Alt+Click selection
In facts I found the answer on [stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-select-columns-in-editors-and-ides-notepad-kate-vim-netbeans)

Sorry if my question my appear stupid to some people.